# How can I create a variable based in the user's input?

Tags: c++, variables, input, user-input

I am trying to program a school bulletin (I'm sorry if that's not the right word, what I meant with "bulletin" is the thing were are the grades of each student. English isn't my 1° language) and I want to ask the user the name of the student and then create a

```
int student_name;
```

so I don't need to create a 1000 of

```
int student_1
int student_2
```

and then just use `cin <<`. So, how can I do that? I hope my question was easy to understand. Thanks!

Comment: How about `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` where the key is the student name and the value is a note. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: You can't create a variable identifier based on input, and you never need to. This is what `std::vector` and arrays and tables like `std::map` are for.

Comment: What to do next depends on what the name is for. Do you intend to locate students by name and store or find out some other information about them, or do you want to collect all your students in one place and then look up their names (and other data)?

Comment: Note that a std::map or std::unordered_map that use the student’s name as a key is going to be problematic if you ever have two students with the same name :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
void createStudent(std::map<string, int>& input)
{
    std::string name;
    int grade;
    for(int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
    {
        std::cin>>name>>grade;
        input.insert(std::pair<string, int>(name, grade));
    }
    return;
}
void showContentMap(std::map<string, int>& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<input[i].first<<" : "<<input[i].second<<std::endl;
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    std::map<string, int> students;
    createStudent(students);
    showContentMap(students);
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. An execution of the command-function `createStudent()` assigns into the parameter `students` their identifiers such as name and grade. It is known that the quantity of students is 1000.
2. The command-function `showContentMap()` demonstrates the content of the parameter `students`.
3. The main properties of a student are **name** and **grade**. These properties will be assigned into the parameter `map<string, int> students`.

Comment: Some things to improve, apart from no written explanation: `using namespace std;`, global variable, hardcoded `std::cin`, map passed by copy, ordered container even though no order required.

Comment: @pptaszni, I have corrected.

Comment: @João Guilherme, if my answer helped to you, mark this question as **solved**.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to create a system that allows you to add and remove student names, it is best to use something like `std::vector<std::string> studentNames;`. Every time that you want to append a new student name, you can use `studentNames.pushBack("John Doe");`.

Remember to `#include <vector>` it at the top of your code.